# Restaurants during Christmas in Norway

Tags: norway, christmas

We are currently planning our annual road trip through Norway over Christmas and newyear. In the past we started after Christmas, but this time we will start earlier and are planning to spend the Christmas eve (December 24th) in or in the general area of Trondheim.

We already focused on the larger cities, assuming that it would be easier to find open venues than in smaller villages, but we already tried to get table reservations in restaurants for that evening and got negative answers that the restaurant is closed on the 24th and the 25th. Can I generally expect that all restaurants are closed on these days? Or can I hope to find something just by walking through the pedestrian zone?

How can I find out if venues are open during Christmas, short of calling or mailing every single one?

Comment: Think about cultural background. For example, Chinese restaurants are often open; depending on what you like, there could be options.

Comment: This might help https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38060/what-will-be-open-during-christmas-in-bergen?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @DumbCoder, I already read that question. It is only about museums and shops though, restaurants usually follow other opening hours.

Comment: Given how difficult it is to find a restaurant open on Christmas in **London**, I’m not betting much on Trondheim. Try restaurants in upscale hotels, but in London even most of those are closed (and many restaurants are closed for several days in a row in that period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Christmas and New Year is in Norway by most people celebrated at home. It would be *very* unusual for a Norwegian family to go out on Christmas Eve. You must expect most restaurants to be closed on December 24th, 25th and 31st and on January 1st. Even between Christmas and New Year, many restaurants are closed, many shops will have reduced opening hours and public transport will follow a reduced schedule.

The same will apply to most foreign, even Asian and Arab restaurants. Even if the owners don't celebrate Christmas, they likely won't bother staying open since they can't expect many customers to show up.

Finding an open restaurant for Christmas Eve and Christmas Day in Trondheim is bound to be difficult, but you may be a little bit early right now. Restaurants will likely publish their opening hours during Christmas on their web pages, but not until a bit closer to Christmas. My best guess would be to check with the larger hotels if they don't keep their restaurants open, but I just called Radisson Blu Royal Garden, one of the largest hotels in Trondheim and their restaurant is closed.

It is probably not of much help for you, but the Oslo newspaper *Aftenposten* traditionally  writes an article shortly before Christmas about 'Where to eat during Christmas and New Year', [here the article from last year](https://www.aftenposten.no/osloby/sulten/i/J19Lk6/her-kan-du-spise-i-julen-og-romjulen). It is however in Norwegian and behind a pay wall. From the freely available introduction, we can read that only 'six restaurants are open on Christmas Eve'. They later state a disclaimer that they don't have a complete overview over all restaurants in Oslo, but I doubt that you would have found many more open places in Oslo.

In Trondheim, the city magazine *trd.by* published a similar overview, here the articles from [2016](https://trd.by/uteliv/2016/12/22/Disse-restaurantene-har-%C3%A5pent-i-romjula-13956525.ece) and [2017](https://trd.by/uteliv/2017/12/22/Lei-av-ribberester-Disse-restaurantene-har-d%C3%B8rene-%C3%A5pne-i-romjula-15746197.ece). They are also in Norwegian, but at least freely available so that you can run them through an online translator. They do however not mention a single restaurant open on December 24th or 25th.

Comment: Thank you very much for all that. That's pretty much what I was afraid of. I guess we'll assume for now that we won't find anything and plan accordingly, if we find something on short notice we can change our plans.

Comment: I managed to get one of the Trondheim Hotel's (the Britannia - the first one I tried) to be willing to book me in from 21 Dec to 28 Dec. This is a relatively expensive hotel and in TripAdvisor's top 10 from Trondheim; I doubt that they'd take my money and then say 'BTW, we can't feed you for 2 days'. Try hotels with their own restaurant in your price range and see how far you get.

Comment: @simonatrcl I would not rely on that. The hotels will be open for guests, but you must expect the restaurants to be closed, expect perhaps for the breakfast buffet.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it was really helpful. We canceled the hotel in Trondheim and decided to rent a cabin at the arctic circle instead. We went shopping on the 23rd and made our own dinner on the 24th and the 25th.

Comment: You can eat enough at the Britannia's breakfast buffet to last until the next morning!